# Serverless - ApiGatewayResourcePostsUseridVar - A sibling ({postId}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In my serverless.yml file I have defined few paths for my lambda functions:

```
GetAllPublicPosts:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/getAllPublicPosts.handler    
    events:      
      - http:         
        method: get          
        path: posts
...
GetAllUserPosts:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/getAllUserPosts.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
        method: get          
        path: posts/{userId}
...
CreatePost:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/createPost.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
        method: post          
        path: posts
...
UpdatePost:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/updatePost.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
        method: patch          
        path: posts/{postId}
...
DeletePost:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/deletePost.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
        method: delete          
        path: posts/{postId}
...
GenerateUploadUrl:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/generateUploadUrl.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
        method: post          
        path: posts/{postId}/attachment
```

When I try to deploy it like that I get an error:

> An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourcePostsUseridVar - A sibling
> ({postId}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only
> one is allowed

I had similar setup for another project and that worked fine. Why do I get this error now?

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know yet why that is the issue, but you cannot have two lambdas there pointing to the same path. Better explained by example:

```
UpdatePost:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/updatePost.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
          method: patch          
          path: posts/{postId} # <- the 'posts/' here
...
DeletePost:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/deletePost.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
          method: delete          
          path: posts/{postId} # <- and the 'posts/' here
```

It would work if you change them to be other words or endpoints such as:

```
UpdatePost:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/updatePost.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
          method: patch          
          path: post/{postId} # <- changed from 'posts/' to 'post/'
...
DeletePost:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/deletePost.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
          method: delete          
          path: posts/{postId}
```

BUT this is obviously not feasible and not nicely readable (looking at all endpoints from a user perspective). In this case, I would recommend to group many of those in one handler such as for example CreatePost, UpdatePost, DeletePost in one handler and then inside that handler differentiate between different method types (POST, PATCH, DELETE) via for example a switch or whatever. Something like this:

```
PostHandler:    
  handler: src/lambda/http/post-handler.handler    
    events:      
      - http:          
          method: patch          
          path: posts/{postId}
      - http:          
          method: delete          
          path: posts/{postId}
```

You can get the method type from the event object of the lambda function handler. This is fix the lambda cold start issue since the container the lambda function will run will be hit more often.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an AWS issue where changing the endpoint variable causes an issue

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3785

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).